# Creating XCFramework can't find a valid framework

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode12, xcframework

I made empty framework project MyFramework and try to create XCFramework

Xcode 12.3, 12.2, 11.7
macOS Catalina, Big Sur

in terminal I write:

```
xcodebuild archive \
-project "MyFramework.xcodeproj" \
-scheme MyFramework \
-archivePath ~/Desktop/MyFramework-iphoneos.xcarchive \
-sdk iphoneos \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

it generates MyFramework-iphoneos.xcarchive successfully

but when I write in terminal:

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework '~/Desktop/MyFramework-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework' -output '~/Desktop/MyFramework.xcframework'
```

it returns error:

```
error: the path does not point to a valid framework: ~/Desktop/MyFramework-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework
```

What is the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that problem was in relative path like "~/Desktop"
Using instead "users/username/documents..." solved this problem